# DOMPDF Font Working But Appearing Very Weird

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf, truetype

I'm adding a custom font to DOMPDF and even though the font itself is working, the characters are just random :-S See image below for what I mean.

[image]

Has anyone had anything like this before?

**Solution:** See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem I found the solution:

1. DO NOT use an online converter to generate the afm/ufm file.
2. You must use the load_fonts.php file that comes with DOMPDF.